# How to find the road direction between current location and stored one?

Tags: ios, objective-c, annotations, mapkit, plist

I am building my application on objective c using mapkit and CLLCOATION framework. I want to get the direction between the current location and fixed location  STORED IN .plist but it doesn't worked with me

I got this error error Error Domain=MKErrorDomain Code=5 "Directions Not Available" {NSLocalizedFailureReason=A route to the destination from its nearest road cannot be determined, MKErrorGEOError=-403, MKDirectionsErrorCode=7, NSLocalizedDescription=Directions Not Available} with handling diretion. to note I used locations in supported apple locations in europe.

I used the following code

```
- (void) getDirection {
    MKDirectionsRequest *request =[[MKDirectionsRequest alloc]init];
    request.source= [MKMapItem mapItemForCurrentLocation];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    CLLocationDegrees longitude = [defaults doubleForKey:@"longitude"];
    CLLocationDegrees latitude = [defaults doubleForKey:@"latitude"];


    MKPlacemark *destinationPlaceMark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude,longitude) addressDictionary:nil];

    MKMapItem *destination = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:destinationPlaceMark];
    request.destination =destination;
    request.transportType=MKDirectionsTransportTypeAny;
    request.requestsAlternateRoutes = NO;
    MKDirections *directions = [[MKDirections alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    [directions calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(MKDirectionsResponse *response, NSError *error) {
         if (error) {
             NSLog(@"error %@ with handling diretion", error);
         } else {
             [self showRoute:response];

         }
     }];
}

- (void)showRoute:(MKDirectionsResponse *)response

{
    for (MKRoute *route in response.routes)
    { NSLog(@"new route");

        [self.map addOverlay:route.polyline level:MKOverlayLevelAboveRoads];

        for(MKRouteStep *step in route.steps)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",step.instructions);
            [self.directionarray addObject:step.instructions];
        }
        NSLog(@"saving direction...");
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setObject:self.directionarray forKey:@"Direction"];
        [defaults synchronize];

    }

}
```